# Cascade - changes are propagated from non owning side as well?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am new to Hibernate. I had read that when using `CascadeType.ALL` to persist, changes are propogated from the owning side. I have below example where I am saving the non owning entity and the owning entity is also saved.

```
class Account { 

    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="account" , cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Transaction> list= new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    
    
}

class Transaction {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="account_id")
    Account account;
}

Account a = new Account("savings");
    
Transaction t1 = new Transaction("shoe purchase", 45);

t1.setAccount(a);

a.getList().add(t1);


accountRepository.save(a); //If cascaded is on account
```

Does it matter which side cascade is on? In this case I could have used `CascadeType.PERSIST`.

Another question I had was do we write unidirectional mapping for `OneToMany`/`ManyToOne` relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does matter. If `cascade` is defined only on parent, when you make any changes on parent and persist it, then the essential changes on children will also be performed, but changing children won't affect parent entity. Same, when only child entity is cascading changes.

Comment: is one better than the other ? Also is it possible to have cascade on both sides?

Comment: Yes I voted but it is not displayed as I am new to this website.

Comment: Done:) Thank you so much for clarifying this for me